# VS2014 Roslyn Diagnostic

Tags: roslyn

I have created a Roslyn code diagnostic in VS2014.
It already split to Common, CSharp, VB.net diagnostics.
I would like to back port it to make it compatible with the VS2013 Roslyn CTP.

Want to avoid having to reimplement it in to using the VS2013 Roslyn CTP.

What can be shared be the two version?
What has to be different?

Answer (score 1):

A number of APIs have changed between Visual Studio "14" and the VS2013 CTP, and we have another set of changes (hopefully the last) coming down the pipe right now. Honestly, I can't recommend anything better than simply trying to rebuild the source you have, seeing what doesn't build, and then fixing it up. You might simply have to maintain two codebases.